# excel checkspelling single cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling a bit with CheckSpelling in Excel. I have a merged cell that I want to check, but only this cell. Here's what I'm doing.

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect strSheetPassword
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set ma = Range("B21").MergeArea
ma.MergeCells = False
Union(Range("B1"), ma(1, 1)).CheckSpelling
ma.MergeCells = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveSheet.Protect strSheetPassword
```

It's checking the cell I want, but it's also checking the rest of the document. In reading other posts, I got the impression that checking a single cell causes CheckSpelling to check the entire document. This is why I put in the Union with the Range("B1") - B1 contains header text that doesn't have any misspellings and is normally locked, so that users can't change it. But, it is still checking the rest of the sheet! I've tried quite a few variations on this, but it still keeps checking the rest of the sheet.

CONCLUSION
I had been under the impression that it was possible to invoke the CheckSpelling form and have it only check certain cells. Apparently, this isn't true. Instead of building my own form, I should be able to get away with checking the whole sheet each time, although I really don't like that. Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: have you tried not to unmerge them ? or do you know in which cell the text is after unmerging ? Whats your result with this line:
Union(Range("A1"), Range("B21").CheckSpelling

Comment: Yes. When I do that, it checks everything else in the sheet, except the cell I want (B1)

Comment: is A1 an empty cell ? so you want b1 to be checked? Then you should  be able to do the trick with Union(Range("A1"), Range("B1").CheckSpelling with the unmerged cells

Comment: Sorry, let me edit the original.

Comment: I'm trying to spellcheck cell B21. I am adding in cell B1 to the union. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

For a single merged cell:

```
Sub spell_me()
    Dim b As Boolean
    b = Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=ActiveCell.Text)
    MsgBox b & vbCrLf & ActiveCell.Address & vbCrLf & ActiveCell.Text
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To find the miscreant word, you could *Split()* the text into individual words and check each word.

Comment: I tried this on a new blank sheet. Try changing the `b = ...` line to the following: `If Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=ActiveCell.Text) = False Then
        ActiveCell.CheckSpelling
    End If`, and you'll see that H11 is also spellcheked.

Comment: @ChuckShultz  Of course..................any *Range().CheckSpelling* checks the entire sheet..............that is why my code only checks the **text of a single cell**............merged or un-merged.

Comment: yes gary's right, what do you want to do with the checked spell ? Highlight the wrong part ?

Comment: @ChuckShultz  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I want to bring up the SpellChecker form and have it only check cell B21. What this solution does is tell me that a word within the cell is misspelled, but it doesn't change the word.

Answer (score 0):

If it is enough if the wrong part gets highlighted you can use this:

```
Sub SpellCheck()
Dim response As Boolean
Dim words As Variant
Dim wordCount As Long
Dim startAt As Long

words = Split(ActiveCell.Text, " ")
'set all of the text to automatic color
ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
For wordCount = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
 response = Application.CheckSpelling(word:=words(wordCount))
 If Not response Then
   'find out where it is in the text and color the font red
   startAt = InStr(ActiveCell.Text & " ", words(wordCount) & " ")
   ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=startAt, Length:=Len(words(wordCount))).Font.Color = vbRed
 End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is nice, but if the user were to correct the offending word, it will still remain red (unless they delete the word and retype it.

Comment: yeah but a simple else in the loop would fix that